# how to replace seqIDs in a fasta file with new seqIDs using biopython

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file that reads like so:

```
>00009c1cc42953fb4702f6331325c7cc
TACGGAGGATGCGAGCGTTATCCGGATTTATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGGTTGTTAAGTCAGTGGTGAAATCGTGTGGCTCAACCATACGGAGCCATTGAAACTGGCGACCTTGAGTGTAAACGAGGTAGGCGGAATGTGACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCTTAGATATGTCACAGAACCCCGATTGCGAAGGCAGCTTACCAGCATACAACTGAC
>000118a5e731455e942c61a82a40367a623088d0
AGAGTTTTATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCGGCAGGCCTAATACATGCAAGTCGGACGGGATCTAAATTTAAGCTTGCTTAAGTTTAGTGAGAGTGGCGCACGGGTGCGTAACGCGTGAGCAACCTACCCATATCAGGGGGATAGCCCGAAGAAATTCGGATTAACACCGCATAACACAGCAATCTCGCATGAGATCACTGTTAAATATTTATAGGATATGGATGGGCTCGCGTGACATTAGCTAGTTGGTAAGGTAACGGCTTACCAAGGCAACGATGTCTAGGGGCTCTGAGAGGAGAATCCCCCACACTGGTACTGAGACACGGACCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAAGGATTATTGGTCAATGGAGGGAACTCTGAACCAGCCATGCCGCGTGCAGGATGACTGCCCTATGGGTTGTAAACTGCTTTTGTCTGGGAATAAACCTTGATTCGTGAATCAAGCTGAATGTACCAGAAGAATAAGGATCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGATCCGAGCGTTATCCGGATTTATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGCTTTATAAGTCAGAGGTGAAAGACGGCAGCTTAACTGTCGCAGTGCCTTTGATACTGTATAGCTTGAATATCGTTGAAGATGGCGGAATGAGACAAGTAGCGGTGAAATGCATAGATATGTCTCAGAACTCCGATTGCGAAGGCAGCTGTCTAAGCGGCAATTGACGCTGATGCACGAAAGCGTGGGGATCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCCTAAACGATGATAACTGGATGTTGGCGATACACAGTCAGCGTCTTAGCGAAAGCGTTAAGTTATCCACCTGGGGAGTACGCCCGCAAGGGTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGAGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGATGATACGCGAGGAACCTTACCCGGGCTTGAAAGTTAGTGAATGCGACAGAGACGTCTCAGTCCTTCGGGACACGAAACTAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGCCGTGAGGTGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCCTATGTTTAGTTGCCAGCATGTAATGATGGGGACTCTAAACAGACTGCCTGCGTAAGCAGCGAGGAAGGTGGGGACGACGTCAAGTCATCATGGCCCTTACGTCCGGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAGCGGGCAGCTACACAGCAATGTGATGCTAATCTCTAAAAGCCATTCACAGTTCGGATAGGGGTCTGCAACTCGACCCCATGAAGTTGGATTCGCTAGTAATCGCGTATCAGCAATGACGCGGT
```

And I want to basically add microbial taxonomy to the seq IDs like so:

d__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Bacteroidales; f__Bacteroidales_RF16_group; g__Bacteroidales_RF16_group; s__uncultured_bacterium|00009c1cc42953fb4702f6331325c7cc

d__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Sphingobacteriales; f__Sphingobacteriaceae; g__Sphingobacterium; s__uncultured_bacterium|000118a5e731455e942c61a82a40367a623088d0

Where the original seqID is appended to the taxonomy with a | as a separator.

Here is my original code that did not work where I made a list of the new seqIDs with the appended taxonomy that I named 'newids_list':

```
with open('allmergedrep-seqsf.fasta') as original, open('allmergedrep-seqsf2.fasta', 'w') as corrected:
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(original, 'fasta'):
        if seq_record.id in newids_list:
            seq_record.id = seq_record.description = newids_list[seq_record.id]
        SeqIO.write(seq_record, corrected, 'fasta')
```

I made the newids_list from a taxonomy file that has the same seqIDs as the fasta file and its in the same order already. ANy help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the result of the new fasta file (just showing first two sequences)

```
>00009c1cc42953fb4702f6331325c7cc
TACGGAGGATGCGAGCGTTATCCGGATTTATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGGTTGT
TAAGTCAGTGGTGAAATCGTGTGGCTCAACCATACGGAGCCATTGAAACTGGCGACCTTG
AGTGTAAACGAGGTAGGCGGAATGTGACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCTTAGATATGTCACAG
AACCCCGATTGCGAAGGCAGCTTACCAGCATACAACTGAC
>000118a5e731455e942c61a82a40367a623088d0
AGAGTTTTATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCGGCAGGCCTAATACATGCAAGTCGGAC
GGGATCTAAATTTAAGCTTGCTTAAGTTTAGTGAGAGTGGCGCACGGGTGCGTAACGCGT
GAGCAACCTACCCATATCAGGGGGATAGCCCGAAGAAATTCGGATTAACACCGCATAACA
CAGCAATCTCGCATGAGATCACTGTTAAATATTTATAGGATATGGATGGGCTCGCGTGAC
ATTAGCTAGTTGGTAAGGTAACGGCTTACCAAGGCAACGATGTCTAGGGGCTCTGAGAGG
AGAATCCCCCACACTGGTACTGAGACACGGACCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAAGG
ATTATTGGTCAATGGAGGGAACTCTGAACCAGCCATGCCGCGTGCAGGATGACTGCCCTA
TGGGTTGTAAACTGCTTTTGTCTGGGAATAAACCTTGATTCGTGAATCAAGCTGAATGTA
CCAGAAGAATAAGGATCGGCTAACTCCGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGATCCGA
GCGTTATCCGGATTTATTGGGTTTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGCTTTATAAGTCAGAGGTGA
AAGACGGCAGCTTAACTGTCGCAGTGCCTTTGATACTGTATAGCTTGAATATCGTTGAAG
ATGGCGGAATGAGACAAGTAGCGGTGAAATGCATAGATATGTCTCAGAACTCCGATTGCG
AAGGCAGCTGTCTAAGCGGCAATTGACGCTGATGCACGAAAGCGTGGGGATCAAACAGGA
TTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCCTAAACGATGATAACTGGATGTTGGCGATACACAGT
CAGCGTCTTAGCGAAAGCGTTAAGTTATCCACCTGGGGAGTACGCCCGCAAGGGTGAAAC
TCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGAGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGATGATAC
GCGAGGAACCTTACCCGGGCTTGAAAGTTAGTGAATGCGACAGAGACGTCTCAGTCCTTC
GGGACACGAAACTAGGTGCTGCATGGCTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGCCGTGAGGTGTTGGGTTA
AGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCCTATGTTTAGTTGCCAGCATGTAATGATGGGGACTCTA
AACAGACTGCCTGCGTAAGCAGCGAGGAAGGTGGGGACGACGTCAAGTCATCATGGCCCT
TACGTCCGGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAGCGGGCAGCTACACAGCAATG
TGATGCTAATCTCTAAAAGCCATTCACAGTTCGGATAGGGGTCTGCAACTCGACCCCATG
AAGTTGGATTCGCTAGTAATCGCGTATCAGCAATGACGCGGT
```

It seems to be identical to above but just reformatted differently..like word wrapped or something.
But basically the seqID is the same.

Also for reference here is my newids_list (first couple new ids):

```
['d__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Bacteroidales; f__Bacteroidales_RF16_group; g__Bacteroidales_RF16_group; s__uncultured_bacterium|00009c1cc42953fb4702f6331325c7cc', 'd__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Sphingobacteriales; f__Sphingobacteriaceae; g__Sphingobacterium; s__uncultured_bacterium|000118a5e731455e942c61a82a40367a623088d0', 'd__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridia_UCG-014; f__Clostridia_UCG-014; g__Clostridia_UCG-014; s__uncultured_bacterium|0001536d70650564fec0c62905eeb73c']
```

where basically I am trying to add taxonomy before the seqID where they are both joined by a '|'.
THank you!

Comment: What is result of your current code? And how does the list `newids_list` look?

Comment: Hi @Vovin I added some edits. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main issue with the code is that you treat `list` as `dict` (your `new_list`) and that the `ID` is really not in the `new_list`, so you are actually not running the rename.

Here is an example of how I would do the rename to get you started

```py
# define new_list as dict with keys being sequence ids and values the taxonomy
new_list = {id: tax for id, tax in zip(LIST_OF_SEQ_IDS, LIST_OF_TAX)} # you need to provide this somehow

original = [s for s in SeqIO.parse('allmergedrep-seqsf.fasta', 'fasta')]
corrected = []
for s in original:
  # here we put the requested ID format
  # note, that the FASTA ID usually do not contain spaces
  s.id = '{}|{}'.format(new_list[s.id], s.id)
  
  # BioPython sometimes adds IDs also here (and in some cases also to "s.name")
  s.description = ''
  
  corrected.append(s)

SeqIO.write(corrected, 'allmergedrep-seqsf2.fasta', 'fasta')
```

If your `new_list` is truly in the same order and does already contain the sequences you want why you don't just:

```py
with open('allmergedrep-seqsf.fasta') as original, open('allmergedrep-seqsf2.fasta', 'w') as corrected:
    for seq_record, new_name in zip(SeqIO.parse(original, 'fasta'), new_list):
        seq_record.id = new_name
        seq_record.description = '' # do you need that taxonomy twice?
        SeqIO.write(seq_record, corrected, 'fasta')
```

Comment: I tried your first code and it worked. Thank you. The only thing I changed was instead of 'fasta' I put 'fasta-2line' for both the original and the output or else biopython outputs a new fasta file that is word wrapped and potentially not usable by other software programs..

Comment: and small typo..there needs to be quotes around the first 'fasta'

Comment: typo fixed, thx